# Eigen reduction examples are not building with Error C2100 illegal indirection

Tags: eigen

I am trying to use examples from

> Reduction Dimensions

section of [Eigen Tensors README](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/677c9f1577810e869f4f09881cabc3e503a810c1/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md)

This:

```
// Create a tensor of 2 dimensions
Eigen::Tensor<int, 2> a(2, 3);
a.setValues({{1, 2, 3}, {6, 5, 4}});
// Reduce it along the second dimension (1)...
Eigen::array<int, 1> dims({1 /* dimension to reduce */});
// ...using the "maximum" operator.
// The result is a tensor with one dimension.  The size of
// that dimension is the same as the first (non-reduced) dimension of a.
Eigen::Tensor<int, 1> b = a.maximum(dims);
cout << "a" << endl << a << endl << endl;
cout << "b" << endl << b << endl << endl;
```

And other examples from that section gives me `Error C2100 illegal indirection` compile error. In VS 2015. Everything else works and compile well. Any ideas what is the problem with that code?

Comment: Copy&paste the complete message. Show the line.

Comment: Error C2100 illegal indirection - that is all. No line displayed. But i know that is Eigen::array<int, 1> dims({1 /* dimension to reduce */});

Comment: Find the real output. In Visual Studio it's the Output tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Eigen::array<int, 1> dims({1 /* dimension to reduce */});
```

Should be changed to:

```
const std::array<DenseIndex, 1> action_cards_dims = { 1 };
```